# Accumulate results from separate web requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

I'm fairly new to both multi-threading and iOS, and I've hit a mental roadblock on how I might approach this problem.  I don't need a ton of code or expect you to write it for me, rather I'm just looking more for the conceptual approach, or perhaps brief pseudocode.

I have an app on iPad.

I have 8 files used by the app stored on Azure (Cloud storage)

The user's can download these 8 files at their whim for use locally on the iPad.

Every 30 min, I check the 8 files on Azure and compare them against the files stored locally for differences.  Each changed file on Azure (call it a hash compare of azure file vs. local file for simplicity) counts as "+1" when counting up the changed files between whats on the iPad vs. whats on Azure.

The problem I'm having is, the way Azure stores files, it is necessary for me to make 2 asynch web requests from the iPad, getting 3 of the 8 files in the first call, and 5 of the 8 files in the second call.

Well, I need to be able to compare all 8 at once in order to be able to update the badge properly with the correct count of how many files have changed.  If I just process the first web call (and say 1 file has changed), then I update the badge with a 1, and a few seconds later the second web request's response comes in, and 3 files have changed, and I update the badge with 3, well, that's incorrect, because it should be 4.  The 1 change from the first web request's response, + the 3 changes from the second web request's response.

So what's the best/simplest way to accumulate the results from these 2 web request responses so that I can do a single comparison of all 8 files at once and update the badge with the proper count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you two ways to complete your task.

1. Simple way. When you start your download requests set updatedFilesCouter to -1. At the end of any operation you need to make your comparison and add to or replace updatedFilesCouter. If first operation is going to change updatedFilesCouter you can notice that your value is always -1, so you need to replace it. If second operation is going to change updatedFilesCouter, then it's value is always different from -1, so you need to add new value. So, if first operation has 2 updated files and second one has 3, then in the end you will get 5, and you can figure out which operation is the last one to update badge value.
2. More advanced way. Make NSOperationsQueue for your download operations. After completion of any operation store files in memory. After completion of NSOperationQueue make comparison and then decide to remove/replace files.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the details, the simplest solution I can think of is to do something like this in an instance that manages the file checks (pseudo-ish code):

```
- (void)checkForUpdate {
  self.runningRequests = 0;
  self.updatedFiles = 0;
  // Launch each necessary request, incrementing runningRequests appropriately.
}

- (void)requestCallbackMethodWithResponse:(id)response {
  self.updateFiles += response.numberOfUpdates; // or whatever your logic
  self.runningRequests--;
  if (self.runningRequests <= 0) {
    // update badge to match updateFiles
  }
}
```

If the callbacks might be coming back from another thread, you can surround the method bodies with `@synchronize(self) { /* actual code */ }`

Comment: If the first spawned request returns a response before the second request is spawned though, then you'd encounter the same problem i'm running into because the runningRequests count would go +1 at spawn, and then -1 at response and update the badge before the second request fired.  Maybe if I started with runningRequests = 2, and then just decrement each response, and when 0, then update badge, I think that would work

Comment: How are you doing your requests? The standard async callback will happen on the main thread, so you might not have as many concurrency problems as you think. But, like you mentioned, you can just set `runningRequests` to what you'd like before kicking off the first requests if you thin you might have a race condition.

Comment: I'm just doing `connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:myRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];` one right after the other, so you're probably right, it would probably be a miracle for the first request to respond before the second even fires.